# Detect and stop Airplay on WKWebView that plays a video

Tags: ios, webkit, airplay, restrict

What I have tried?

- UIScreen.screens.count > 1

```
Ans : Always getting one even though my app is currently Airplay(ing) on my Macbook
```

- Setting configuration of WKWebView

```
mediaPlaybackAllowsAirPlay = false
allowsAirPlayForMediaPlayback = false
Although the airplay button is not present in the player controls but one can still caste using the control panel airplay button by swipping the screen from above.
```

- Tried this method used widely to detect Airplay but it only detects in case of screen mirroring no callbacks for Airplay.

```
func isAirplayOn() -> Bool {
    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    let currentRoute = audioSession.currentRoute
    for outputPort in currentRoute.outputs {
      if outputPort.portType == AVAudioSession.Port.airPlay {
        return true
      }
    }
    return false
}
```

So to my vain this also does not work.
Let me know how to either detect airplay or disable it on WKWebView's Audio/Video Player.
Any help will be highly appreciated.